# Proof that $x^4 + 4y^4$ cannot be $z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

How do I prove that $x^4 + 4y^4 \neq z^2$ if $xyz \neq 0$ ? I was reading this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1451.pdf (2.1) and am not able to follow the part of the proof on page 3.

I want to know this for a presentation I am doing on impossible diophantine equations.

Update: I edited some stuff that was commented about. Thank you.

Comment: Rather than just saying you can't find an understandable proof, can you say what proofs you found and *why* you didn't understand them? Otherwise, someone is likely to just copy them here, wasting everyone's time. Regardless, a standard technique here is to make an infinite descent argument.

Comment: Did you mean proving that $x^4+4y^2$ for integers $x,y$, cannot be a perfect square?

Comment: Take $x=2$ and $y=0$ and $z=4$.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about that proof? Why do you need to know this? Etc.

Comment: @Michael It should be a nontrivial solution.

Comment: @TrầnThúcMinhTrí Note it's now $4y^4.$

Comment: @coffeemath Now fixed to $4y^4$ and also $xyz\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

On page 2, right after equations (2), he gets to $x_0^2=s_0^4-t_0^4.$ If you're willing to accept it as known that a (nontrivial) difference of fourth powers cannot be a square then there's the contradiction already. This fact was already known to Fermat and has an infinite descent proof; there are other approaches to showing it, and the paper you quote seems to go on and bring out such an approach. [I don't know why the author wasn't willing at that point to just quote the difference of fourth powers result.]

Comment: I actually wanted to know the answer to this question because I was reading the link below and it uses the $x^4 + 4y^4 \neq z^2$ to prove that $z^2 \neq x^4 - y^4$ for non-trivial x,y, and z.https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/Curso/Problemas/problemas%20capitulo%204/Ejercicio%204.3.9.pdf

Comment: @user244138 Well that's a surprise (to me). I remember going through a proof of $z^2 \neq x^4-y^4$ but it was so long ago I don't recall whether that proof used the $x^4+4y^4 \neq z^2$ result or not. If I can find the difference of fourth powers result I'll add something.